# Sass: Declarations may only be used within style rules

Tags: sass

I am getting a sass error: Declarations may only be used within style rules.

```
   ╷
32 │     #{$property}: $value;
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

for the following file:

```
@mixin theme($colour, $texture: null) {
  $theme: map-get-strict($themes, $colour, "theme");

  @if ($texture) {
    @include getTexture($texture);
  }

  @each $property, $value in $theme {
    #{$property}: $value;
  }
}
```

This is using dart-sass.

I think it might be a Sass test file that is causing the issue, e.g.:

```
@include it('outputs the light-blue theme') {
    @include assert {
      @include output {
        @include theme(light-blue);
      }

      @include expect {
        background-color: getColour(light-blue);
        color: getColour(black);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you including the mixin in a selector?

Comment: The mixin is also used in test files, which might be what's at fault. I added some code to my question

Comment: You can't include this mixin at root, it needs a parent selector, that is what the error means.

Comment: So how should the test be written?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, sorry. I didn't even know writting tests for SASS was a thing.

Answer (score 15):

> Declarations may only be used within style rules.

You can only use declarations *within* style rules. This means if you have a mixin which contains declarations

*E.g.:*

```
@mixin foo() {
  color: #000;
}
```

you can *only* include it *within* a style rule.

*E.g.:*

```
.bar {
  @include foo();
}
```

---

This helps to ensure that the compiled CSS is free of errors.

---

<s>color: #000;</s>

```
.bar {
  color: #000;
}
```